# resize external SVG, how do you resize external SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

though previously asked, the answer given dosent work. How do you resize an external svg?

```
<body>
    <img class="region" src="svg/ke.svg" alt="">
</body>
```

i expected this css to work but it does not

```
.region{
    height: 1em;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the SVG file? There is probably a width and/or height attribute defined on the SVG element. You can remove those and if there is no viewBox attribute defined, create one with the same values as the width and the height attribute. `<svg width="64" height="32">` become `<svg viewBox="0 0 64 32">`.